# add break line in table

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I am trying to replicate the table like the below one.

I know I can use  `\toprule`, `\hline` to add lines in the table. However, I do not know how a add a broken line in the table as row two and three shows between "A" and "B" or "B"& "C"

```
\begin{table}
  \caption{CAPTION}
  \label{tab:TABLENAME}
  \begin{tabular}{ccl}
    \toprule
      A & B & C\\
    \midrule
  
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use an empty column.

Comment: @gernot  but the line between row 3 and 4 is continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\cmidrule` (from `booktabs` package) as in

```
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
```

which will draw a line between columns 2 and 3, trimmed both `l`eft and `r`ight.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {booktabs}
\usepackage   {lipsum} % for dummy text


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]\centering
\caption{CAPTION\strut}\label{tab:TABLENAME}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
CATEGORIES & (1) & (2) & (1) & (2) & (1) & (2) \\
\midrule
GOOD & & & & & & \\
BAD  & & & & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfecr thanks!